# How to run another function as async in rust?

Tags: rust, async-await

as a JS dev i'm having a real hard time understanding error handling in rust. especially with asyncronisity. heres some code from another stackoverflow question using `async-std` to call an async scraper function:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{self, BufReader};
use std::io::BufRead;
//use async_std::task;

async fn scrape<R: BufRead>(reader: &mut R) -> io::Result<()> {
    reader.lines()
        .try_for_each(|line_result| line_result.and_then(|line| Ok(println!("{}", line))))?;
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    let file_result = File::open("wlist.txt");
    let file;
    match file_result {
       Ok(f) => file = f,
       Err(e) => { println!("File open error! {}", e); return; },
    }
    let mut reader = BufReader::new(file);

    match scrape(&mut reader) {
        Ok(_) => println!("done!"),
        Err(e) => println!("File read error! {}", e),
    }
}
```

I'm trying to call `scrape` in an asyncronous way like:

```
    task::block_on(match scrape(&mut reader) {
        Ok(_) => println!("done!"),
        Err(e) => println!("File read error! {}", e),
    })
```

but it errors with
`the trait std::future::Future is not implemented for ()`

What's wrong with the code snippet? how can I run scraper as async with as less modification to the rest of the code as possible?

Answer (score 2):

Usually you can only call async functions from async context, except when you use the `block_on` or `spawn` functions or similar from your executor.

The easiest way to create an async context is an `async` block. Then you need to use the `.await` operator to properly chain asyncs:

```
    task::block_on(async {
        match scrape(&mut reader).await {
            Ok(_) => println!("done!"),
            Err(e) => println!("File read error! {}", e),
        }
    })
```

For more complex code you will have an async function that may fail that calls another async function that also may fail. In those cases it is idiomatic to write `other_async_func().await?` to await and forward the error at the same time.

Comment: this returns
```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::result::Result<(), std::io::Error>: std::future::Future` is not satisfied
  --> src\main.rs:22:15
   |
22 |         match scrape(&mut reader).await {
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::future::Future` is not implemented for `std::result::Result<(), std::io::Error
```

Comment: This means that you are using `.await` is something that is not a `Future`, probably because you removed the `async` from `async fn scrape(...)`. Either add `async` to the function or remove the `.await` from the call. Naturally, your code does not have any async I/O so it will make no difference in practice.